# Embeded Hashtags on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hashtag

I want to get all the posts (ifram) for a particular hash tag in facebook. Like twitter widgets. i managed to do it with twitter , please advice me how to proceed this using facebook?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no Facebook hashtag API.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using a query where you search for the text of the hashtag.  But instead of using the `#` character, use `%23`

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/search?q=%23TheHashtag
```

Note that you need to use the v1.0 API to do this.  Searching Posts has been deprecated in 2.0. Remember that you can only use the v1.0 API if your app was created prior to April 30, 2014:

> For apps created before April 30th 2014, making API calls without
>   specifying a version number is equivalent to calling v1.0 of the API.
>
> For apps created on or after April 30th 2014, making API calls without
>   specifying a version number is equivalent to calling v2.0 of the API.
>   These apps won't be able to call v1.0 of the API.